# Unable to customize django-oscar model

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am trying to customize a django-oscar model. ( I am using version 2.0.3 )

I have created a separate folder labeled `apps` and have created my app in it. I want to customize `Product` model in `catalogue`

My `INSTALLED_APPS` look like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    'oscar',
    'oscar.apps.analytics',
    'oscar.apps.checkout',
    'oscar.apps.address',
    'oscar.apps.shipping',
    # 'oscar.apps.catalogue',
    # 'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews',
    'oscar.apps.partner',
    'oscar.apps.basket',
    'oscar.apps.payment',
    'oscar.apps.offer',
    'oscar.apps.order',
    'oscar.apps.customer',
    'oscar.apps.search',
    'oscar.apps.voucher',
    'oscar.apps.wishlists',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.users',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.orders',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.offers',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.partners',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.pages',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.ranges',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reviews',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.vouchers',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.communications',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.shipping',

    # 3rd-party apps that oscar depends on
    'widget_tweaks',
    'haystack',
    'treebeard',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'django_tables2',
    'rest_framework',
    'apps.catalogue'
]
```

and `apps/catalogue/models.py` looks like this

```
from django.db import models

from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct
# from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *

class Product(AbstractProduct):
    custom_tag_field = models.CharField(default="Pending", max_length=100)

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

I keep getting this error when I try to migrate and unable to solve it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/wigme/apps/catalogue/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py", line 29, in <module>
    BrowsableProductManager = get_class('catalogue.managers', 'BrowsableProductManager')
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 31, in get_class
    return get_classes(module_label, [classname], module_prefix)[0]
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 41, in get_classes
    return class_loader(module_label, classnames, module_prefix)
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 104, in default_class_loader
    app_name = _find_registered_app_name(module_label)
  File "/home/abhijit/e-commerce-wig/oscar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 189, in _find_registered_app_name
    "Couldn't find an Oscar app to import %s from" % module_label)
oscar.core.exceptions.AppNotFoundError: Couldn't find an Oscar app to import catalogue.managers from
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!!

Comment: Please show us your forked app's `AppConfig`, and `__init__.py`. Looking at what you've posted it seems likely your `AppConfig` isn't subclassing `OscarConfig`, or isn't specified as the `default_app_config` in your init file.

Comment: Yes @solarissmoke! This was the issue! It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, I had created the app using Django's `startapp` command and did not fork it using management command provided by oscar. If we use `startapp` command then we need to make following change.

(I overrode `catalogue` app)

Add this line in `__init__.py` of the app

`default_app_config = 'catalogue.apps.CatalogueConfig'`

And edit the `apps.py` as

```
import oscar.apps.catalogue.apps as apps

class CatalogueConfig(apps.CatalogueConfig):
    name = 'catalogue'
    label = 'catalogue'
    verbose_name = 'Catalogue'
```